# How to remove AbstractHttpConfigurer from default HttpSecurity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-autoconfiguration

I'm creating an internal lib, and I want to perform some autoconfiguration that involve removing security customizers that are added by default, for example `LogoutConfigurer`, as if it was not part of the default `HttpSecurity` prototype bean:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain authFilter(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                   // I want to make this unnecessary by not being part of the (adjusted) HttpSecurity
                   //.logout().disable()
                   .authorizeRequests()
                   .mvcMatchers("/secured").hasRole("ROLE")
                   .anyRequest().denyAll()
                   .and()
                   .build(); // (1)
    }
```

The way to customize security in a cross-cutting way like that seems to be implementing `AbstractHttpConfigurer` beans, yet those are only triggered as part of the `HttpScurity#build()` method that generates a `SecurityFilterChain` as part of the main application security configuration code (marked as `(1)` above). That is too late, as my bean would need to be undoing the configuration done by another customizer just before it, which is complicated and maybe not possible (removing filters, etc).

The only alternative I found so far seems to be overriding the `AbstractHttpConfigurer#setBuilder(B)` to manipulate the given builder (the `HttpSecurity` object) into removing the customizers, given that this method is called right after `HttpSecurity` is created and before making it accessible as a prototype bean:

```
public class MyHttpConfigurer extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<MyHttpConfigurer, HttpSecurity> {

    @Override
    public final void setBuilder(HttpSecurity http) {
        super.setBuilder(http);

        try {
            // Do this and/or whatever else you want to do
            http.logout().disable();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("It failed", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {}
}
```

It works as I want, but that looks unstable, abusing the API, and feels it might break without warning. I also found no way to replace the default `HttpSecurity` prototype builder as it is not conditional.

Is there a cleaner or documented way to achieve this?

Comment: I think there is an issue that may help you. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11633

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio yes, that's pretty much my case, except that I'm not for all-or-nothing on defaults, I want something more granular. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Please consider upvoting the issue and sharing your use case so the issue can be prioritized based on users' feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the cleanest approach for you to achieve your functionality would be to provide a `BeanPostProcessor`.

e.g.

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class CustomSecurityConfiguration {

    private static final String HTTP_SECURITY_DEFAULT_BEAN_NAME = "org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity";

    @Bean
    public static BeanPostProcessor httpSecurityBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new BeanPostProcessor() {

            @Override
            public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                if (bean instanceof HttpSecurity && HTTP_SECURITY_DEFAULT_BEAN_NAME.equals(beanName)) {
                    HttpSecurity http = (HttpSecurity) bean;
                    try {
                        http.logout().disable();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
                return bean;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

This is really similar to the example you've proposed. In any case, I do not thing that it is abusing the API since it allows for accessing the `HttpSecurity`

Comment: You know, you're absolutely right! I forgot about post processors, and in this case they do a much cleaner job. Maybe a future API can make it such tweaks more "explicit" with `HttpSecurity,` but this is definitely better than the `setBuilder()` way. Some of the adjustments still require `AbstractHttpConfigurer` (if they need to happen just before `SecurityFilterChain` creation) but in those cases the API is sufficient for the job. Thanks a lot!